# Teamcity environment variables lowercase/uppercase collisions

Tags: linux, teamcity, agent

Using Teamcity ver. 10.0.4 I have spotted strange behaviour when defining environment variables with same name but in different cases, e. g. "env.proxy" and "env.PROXY" on both linux and mac agents, variables get propagated on agents and builds exposing them as expected. But when I go to Agent Parameters->Environment Variables and see only variable "PROXY" (defined in uppercase). Teamcity runs under JDK 1.8.0_121. Does somebody faced such an issue?

Comment: How are you defining the variables? Directly on the agents, through build parameters or set up as a build step? If on the build configuration, do the agents have the parameter set up previously, or is it exclusively defined in the configuration?

Comment: I've been defining variables on agents through sysvinit script. Agents have defined variables on them during the build, but the uppercase variables are only visible in the Teamcity UI.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Managed to replicate the issue. Reported the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-51294, feel free to watch and vote.